# Python Framework Django vs Flask

Tags: python

I was working on web application with PHP and developed a MVC model by myself. Now due to some reason we are shifting to python.
I have some experience with Django framework. But Now with my new web application I want to develop it in python and I will design my own MVC model in it.
I am not sure that I will be able to do it python So, can you guys help me with some knowledge.

1. Can I use python to create my own MVC model without Django and Flask?
2. Will it be feasible and good option to create my own MVC and not using Django or Flask?

Comment: Why would you do this? You're making tons of work for yourself with no benefit. Use a framework.

Comment: @Compsci_guy 1. yes. 2. no

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can I use python to create my own MVC model without Django and Flask?

Yes obviously you can!

> Will it be feasible and good option to create my own MVC and not using Django or Flask?

No. Talking about Django in particular. Some of its awesome features are that it is:

> Ridiculously fast.
>   Django was designed to help developers take applications from concept to completion as quickly as possible.
>
> Reassuringly secure.
>   Django takes security seriously and helps developers avoid many common security mistakes.
>
> Exceedingly scalable.
>   Some of the busiest sites on the Web leverage Django’s ability to quickly and flexibly scale

And for you to achieve the same would definitely take a long time. Moreover when you already have something ready-made for you, why to start from scratch?
I would suggest you to go with the already present frameworks (if your sole motive is to complete your web application
). I am sure that Django already has all the features that you will need in your web app.

Comment: I will be using my Python app as an App Engine and will generate code for Nodejs by it to provide multiple CRM.
Can I be able to do this with Django? Also customizing it's internals may not be easy due to how everything is stitched together.
what about Flask? it's lightweight and versatile I read.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I use python to create my own MVC model without Django and Flask?

Short answer: YES!

Explanation: As Django and Flask web frameworks are built using Python, Sure You can build your own MVC model, but it requires a lot of understanding of how Model-View-Controller(MVC) works.

> Will it be feasible and good option to create my own MVC and not using Django or Flask?

Short answer: NO!

Explanation: Unless you are not completely satisfied with the Django/Flask model and your project requires additional features which are not present in existing frameworks, it would be a better idea if you use existing frameworks because existing web frameworks solve the majority of the problems and are efficient in execution, scalable and simple to use and understand.

Answer (score 0):

paradocslover appart from answering the OP's questions mentions a couple of interesting Django's advantages.

So, to take that a step further, people arriving here may find bellow a table of important features provided **out-of-the-box** for each of the 2 frameworks.

### Baseline built-in provided features

| Built-in Features | Django | Flask |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Security | [✓](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/security/) | [✓](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/security/) |
| database ORM | ✓ | ✗ |
| database migrations | ✓ | ✗ |
| DRY | ✓ (model->serializer/form->view->template with a single source of truth - the model - and minimal code) | self-coded flow ([CBVs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/views/) provided) |
| testing | [✓](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/testing/) | [requires pytest](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/testing/) |
| rest api + rest docs (openAPI) | ✗ (build manually) | (easy to generate directly from [swagger.io](https://editor.swagger.io/)) |
| templates | [Django Template Language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/templates/) | requires jinja2 installation |
| async support | [not that good](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/async/) | [easy and efficient](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/async-await/) |